# How to append user defined legend to existing legend in gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot, legend

I create with gnuplot the graph below, but now I want to add to legend (titles) extra value that not inside plot data.

I draw vertical with `set arrow` and add label to identification.

```
set label "Ef" at (Ef+0.5),-20
#some other code
plot
```

and

```
set style line 11 lc rgb 'black' lt 1 dt "-" lw 1 pt 5 ps 1.5 pi 4  # --- black dashed
set style arrow 1 nohead front  ls 11
set arrow arrowstyle 1 from Ef,GPVAL_DATA_Y_MIN to Ef,GPVAL_DATA_Y_MAX
replot
```

Ef is a dummy variable (Ef = 5 in this case)

But I want add Ef to legend with dashed line.

How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: This is also the use-case for adding asymptotes or reference values to a plot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gnuplot draws the whole plot at once, so there is no way to add something to an existing plot.  Thus we have to "trick" it into drawing the legend entry for that line at the beginning.

The best way is to plot a function which is undefined.  When gnuplot encounters undefined points, it just skips them, so plotting the function 1/0 will cause no points to be drawn.

Consider

```
set arrow 1 from 2,graph 0 to 2,graph 1 lt 0 nohead
plot [-5:5][-2:2] sin(x) t "Sine", 1/0 t "Extra"
```

[image: Example Image]

This will add a legend entry for that dotted line, but the plot command does not draw such a line.

Comment: Thanks! This trick work perfectly.... Other question, How do you get that vertical line going to bottom to top complete?

Comment: Gnuplot has several coordinate systems (first, second, graph, and screen for instance, although there may be a few more).  By default, your coordinates are in the first system which corresponds to your y axis.  Notice in my code that I specify "2,graph 0" and "2,graph 1" as coordinates.  The graph before the y coordinate means to use the graph system which always runs from 0 to 1.  Thus I have specified an arrow from the bottom of the graph to the top.  In the gnuplot manual look up "coordinates" (page 23 in the current 5.0 manual pdf).